# Show all 4 digit numbers (but not the whole line and exclude special characters appended to number) using regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find and print all 4 digit numbers (but not the whole line) in a file using regex in bash.

My sample file looks like this:

```
12
123
1234
2345 foo foo foo 
foo foo 3456 foo foo
# 8912 foo foo foo foo
#7654
-8999
\6478
/9023
$7654
A3356
8349B
1439$
1762\
12345
123456
0000
0001
```

I would like my output to include only 4 digits numbers (any number that has normal or special characters appended to it must be ignored):

```
1234
2345
3456
8912
0000
0001
```

The closest I have been able to come to this is:

```
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{4}($|[^0-9])' file_with_numbers.txt
```

which errantly captures numbers with special characters appended and also prints the whole line when I only want the six values as shown above:

```
1234
2345 foo foo foo foo
foo foo 3456 foo foo
# 8912 foo foo foo foo
#7654
-8999
\6478
/9023
$7654
A3356
1439$
1762\
0000
0001
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the exact desired output are appreciated. I am having trouble finding info for the appended special character exclusion as well as showing only the number and not the whole line.

Comment: Can you have `14.56` or `234.456.457` like examples in the string? If yes, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: good question. If that did occur I would want to omit the result such 12.34

Comment: Ok, then use `grep -Po '(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\.?\d)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `(^|[^0-9])` and `($|[^0-9])` will make it part of the match.

You can make use of lookarounds asserting a whitespace boundary on the left and right.

To make use of the lookarounds, you can use `-P` to enable Perl compatible regular expressions.

```
grep -Po '(?<!\S)[0-9]{4}(?!\S)' file_with_numbers.txt
```

Output

```
1234
2345
3456
8912
0000
0001
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` means: "show me the lines which contain a pattern."

When you want to say "**Only** show me the pattern", you need to use the `-o` switch.

So, in your case:

```
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{4}($|[^0-9])' file_with_numbers.txt
```

Should become:

```
grep -Eo '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{4}($|[^0-9])' file_with_numbers.txt
```